# how to clear all sessions associated with a user with passport.js

Tags: passport.js

I know how to log out a user when he requests to do so, but e.g. when he changes his password, I would like to log out all sessions that are currently active with the user.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks & Cheers!
Freundschaft

Comment: does this also clear all other sessions that exist for the user?

Comment: `req.session.destroy()` is what you're looking for I think.

Comment: BTW, sessions are browser-server dependent (nothing to do with user auth/passport stuff), and so if you expect users to be logging in from different browsers and want to clear those sessions as well, you might need some logic to check for something like a `user.hasReset` flag on each request and clear sessions based on that.

Comment: that souds reasonable, I was just wondering if passport.js would have something like this already built in. Thanks!